# how to fix the crash "UIStatusBarDisplayItemState updatePlacement "?

Tags: ios, uistatusbar

i get the crash when excute the code `[_UIStatusBarDisplayItemState updatePlacement]` from the crash log, the crash log says **The item state should have been data updated before updating its placement**，and the crash happens in `iOS 12.x`

Comment: We have the same crash on iOS 12 and iOS 13.